# Order of list in inner join matter for performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("------{0} loop------", i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                List<int> numberList1 = new List<int>();
                for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    numberList1.Add(new Random().Next(1, 10000));
                }

                List<int> numberList2 = new List<int>();
                for (int j = 1; j < 10000; j++)
                {
                    numberList2.Add(new Random().Next(1, 10000));
                }

                Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var temp1 = (from n1 in numberList1
                             join n2 in numberList2
                             on n1 equals n2
                             select n2).ToList();

                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();

                var temp2 = (from n2 in numberList2
                             join n1 in numberList1
                             on n2 equals n1
                             select n2).ToList();

                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output in ms

| Loop | Join 1 | Join 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34262 | 28334 |
| 2 | 10614 | 24367 |
| 3 | 11760 | 22715 |
| 4 | 9945 | 31258 |
| 5 | 12717 | 32469 |
| 6 | 8550 | 24521 |
| 7 | 3392 | 8936 |
| 8 | 1672 | 5140 |
| 9 | 11028 | 32656 |
| 10 | 10929 | 15162 |

Why does execution time differ in both cases? Also is this apply to SQL server 2014?

Comment: Have you actually looked at what's going into your lists? Does it closely resemble your actual data? Because usually creating new `Random` instances in a loop produces... problematic results.

Comment: Use `BenchmakDotnet` for such microbenchmarks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but the calculatwd time is just for join.

Comment: @Blue - but my point is, if the join is between two lists that contain data that is *unrepresentative* of your real data, what has this whole thing actually told you?

Comment: I agree. You're measuring the effect of two factors (randomization and join order) without knowing how they are correlated. In other words, change one factor at a time: only join order, using constant lists.

Answer (score 0):

your test in not wrong in illustrating linq to objects behavior of join. If you think about it how would you implement that? While not having anything additional like indexes your only choice is to have two nested loops that find matching elements. In your test you have a small collection numberList1 and a large one numberList2 so basically you have:

```
foreach(var n1 in numberList1)
    foreach(var n1 in numberList2)
```

in first case and other around in second.

you can make it better by converting one of the collections to lookup essentially creating an index by iterating it once and using that in a loop:

```
var lookup = createLookup(numberList2, getKeyFromN2)
foreach(var n1 in numberList1)
{
    var n2 = lookup[getKeyFromN1(n1)];
```

Now regarding the sizes of those collections it is better to create a lookup for the larger collection and use it in a loop that has small count of items.

As to relevance of this test to any database engine - it has none. Database engines have a lot of metadata about tables at their disposal that can increate performance dramatically like indexes and statistics and if set up properly order of joins will not matter as sql engine will just swap that order around if it deems it advantageous - although it was true that order of joins mattered in sql server I do not remember the version where they implemented the 'smart' query executor.

[real implementation for join iterator in linq to objects](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L695)